# Python Script unable to import installed modules when called as a subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, python-2.6

I've two Python scripts as given below

**inner.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python  
import os  
import datetime  
# <---- Some Code--->
```

**main.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python  
import os  
import datetime  

# <---- Some Code--->  
subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/python",inner.py])
```

The problem is when the `inner.py` script is called from the `main.py` script it doesn't import any modules. For example it says

```
ImportError: No module named os
```

But when the script is executed standalone it works fine. Please help

Comment: That should all work just fine; you can also use `sys.executable` instead of `/usr/bin/python` to make sure you are using the exact same Python binary.

Comment: What does `import sys` do? If that works, what does `print sys.path` give you?

Comment: import sys works and the print sys.path gives the following result  ['/home/transfer/scripts/common', '/usr/bin/python/lib64/python26.zip', '/usr/bin/python/lib64/python2.6/', '/usr/bin/python/lib64/python2.6/plat-linux2', '/usr/bin/python/lib64/python2.6/lib-tk', '/usr/bin/python/lib64/python2.6/lib-old', '/usr/bin/python/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload']

Comment: Your import exception makes no sense. Are you 100% certain that `os` fails to import? Does `import subprocess` work? Does `import urllib` work?

Comment: Yes, all the modules I've mentioned in the inner.py fails except import sys. So far I've import os, import datetime in the inner.py. As per your suggestion I just added import subprocess and even that failed

Answer (score 1):

The following works perfectly fine for me, and it's modified because some of your code seemed a little incomplete.

**inner.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import datetime

print os.getcwd()
```

**main.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import datetime
import subprocess
import sys

# <---- Some Code--->
subprocess.call([sys.executable, "inner.py"])
```